# Class level spinner object unresolvable from method in same class in Android

Tags: java, android, button

Trying my hand at java and android and have run into a problem which I cannot determine is java related, or android related. Essentially I have created some spinners with AdapterArrays on the main onCreate method of the activity, the indices of which I would like to reference from a method I've created which is called from a button using the android:onclick xml attribute.

However, the  onclick method cannot resolve the spinner object I am referencing. I imagine I am improperly placing the code somewhere within the app, and since I'm very new to java I'm not sure if I'm supposed to be overriding the method, and what I'm doing the the View parameter which the android documentation says I am required to pass. Psedo XML as follows:

```
<Button
 android:onclick="method" />
```

Pseduo app.java as follows:

```
public class sampleApp extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
Spinner cloudSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.cloud_spinner);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> cloudAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.cloud_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
cloudAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
cloudSpinner.setAdapter(cloudAdapter);
}

public void method(View v){
if(cloudSpinner.getSelectedItem()){
}

}
}
```

From there the spinner object is unresolvable. Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spinner cloudSpinner is declared inside onCreate().Move it outside.That will solve 'spinner object is unresolvable' problem.

Comment: I omitted a curly bracket on the post here, but in my actual code that is not the case. The method is declared outside onCreate, but inside the class.